# Calculating determinant matrix with size of n

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

we got the following matrix in order of $n$x$n$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & . & . & . & 0 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & . & . & . & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & . & . & .\\
. & . & . & . & . & . & .\\
. & . & . & . & . & . & .\\
0 & . & . & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & . & . & . & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I need to calculate the determinant of the matrix. 
I started to do a row reduction as follows:

```
R2 = R2 - R1,
R3 = R3 - R2,
...,
Rn = Rn - Rn-1
```

and from what I have seen I have reached the following matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & . & . & . & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & . & . & . & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & . & . & 1\\
. & . & . & . & . & . & -1\\
. & . & . & . & . & . & 1\\
0 & . & . & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & . & . & . & 0 & 0 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

So I believe that when $n$ is odd then the determinant of $|A|$ is $|A|=2$ and when its double then its $|A|=0$

but I am not sure I solved it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix is the sum between an identity matrix and a circulant matrix, so the characteristic polynomial is given by:
$$ p(\lambda)=(1-\lambda)^n-(-1)^n \tag{1}$$
and the determinant is given by $(-1)^n p(0)$, so it is $2$ if $n$ is odd and zero otherwise.

Comment: I followed the Triangular matrix determinant formula. to multiply the diagional line of the matrix. and it looks like your solution is the opposite of mine. do you have any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: @DinRevah: it looks to me that we agree: odd dimension, determinant $2$. Even dimension, determinant $0$.

Comment: Ok you've edited the formula I just noticed it thanks!